# Accessing GeoJSON properties after loading the WFS features on the map

Tags: openlayers, geojson, wfs

I use the following code to get WFS features on the map.

```
let WFSlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: layer,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "/proxy/?layer_name=" + layer + "&bbox=" + [bbox[1], bbox[0], bbox[3], bbox[2]],
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(243,20,20,0.3)',
            width: 15
        })
    }),
})
```

I want to access the properties of the loaded features. How should I do it?

This is what my GeoJSON looks like

```
features: [{type: "Feature", id: "", geometry: {type: "MultiLineString",…},…}]
0: {type: "Feature", id: "", geometry: {type: "MultiLineString",…},…}
geometry: {type: "MultiLineString",…}
geometry_name: "geom"
id: ""
properties: {rc_id: 530530, local_id: 0, dot_id: 6811526, mfips: "51001", geo_et: 0, geo_effdt: null,…}
add_ed: null
add_format: "A"
add_lf: 21321
add_lt: 21451
```

Comment: `feature.getProperties()` for the properties object, `feature.getKeys()` for the property names, `feature.get(key)` for a single property value https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
WFSlayer.getSource().once('change', function (event) {
    let source = event.target
    if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
        source.getFeatures().forEach(feature=>{
            console.log(feature.getProperties())
        })
    }
});
```